# Get tweets of a user using API

Tags: php, curl, twitter, posts, tweets

I have the details for user XXXX1

```
 $oauth_access_token = "XXXXX";
   $oauth_access_token_secret = "XXXXX";
    $consumer_key = "XXXXX";
    $consumer_secret = "XXXXX";
```

I am getting the tweets of `XXXXX1` by using curl with `$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";`, but I want to get the tweets of other users like  `XXXXX2,XXXXX3,....`

which API I need to use, suggest me pls.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [twitter API page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) you can specify additional parameters to GET query, and there is user_id or screen_name parameters that you need.

So basically you need to run this type of request for each user:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=12345
```

where 12345 is twitter user id.

Comment: it's showing the error message `{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}`

Comment: Before you can query the twitter API you should authenticate within it, that's why you need all those secrets and passwords. Twitter uses oAuth as API authentication service.

Please show me more code, specifically how you connect and send auth details to twitter.